# Replacement for "stdout" in Rcpp

Tags: c, r, rcpp

While interfacing a C/C++ library in R using Rcpp, what should be the replacement for `stdout`. I know the replacements for `printf` and `cout` to be `Rprintf` and `Rcout` but have not came across anything for `stdout` itself.

C code that is using `stdout` while comparing to a `FILE*` is

```
FILE* fp;
...
if (NULL != fp && stdout != fp)
        (void) fclose(fp);
```

`R CMD check` complains about that with the below error

> Found ‘___stdoutp’, possibly from ‘stdout’ (C)
>       Object: ‘io_png.o’

What is the alternative for `stdout` in Rcpp?

Comment: Just comment-out or remove the `&& stdout != fp` part. R wants you to use its input/output -- see the _Writing R Extensions_ manual.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel thanks! I did that early on too. Was just reassuring and thinking if there is any better way to do things. But this also works.